# how to add dayjs in ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dayjs

I add this https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.10.4/dayjs.min.js file into javascript/packs and

```
require("packs/dayjs.min.js")
```

I'm not sure, maybe I need to load some plugins?
I want to know how can I convert datetime attribute for clients in them timezone on a .html.erb?
I didn't find any examples of use, I will be glad for any help.
in my application.js I want to use something as

```
$('.timestring').each(function() {
  this.textContent = dayjs(this.textContent).format();
});
```

but I don't know how to implement it in erb + application.js

Comment: This might help - https://day.js.org/docs/en/installation/browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My way to add dayjs to Rail 6.1.3, first run commands:

```
$ yarn add jquery
$ yarn add dayjs
```

Then write this code to config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    dayjs: 'dayjs/dayjs.min'
  })
)
module.exports = environment
```

And call it to run app/javascript/packs/application.js, all will be ok!

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

require("jquery")
require("dayjs")

jQuery(function(){
  alert(dayjs().format('{YYYY} MM-DDTHH:mm:ss SSS [Z] A'))
})
```

Bonus, example use javascript function to show local datetime: Create table Event with 2 fields: name:string, starts_at:datetime.

```
$ rails generate model Event name:string starts_at:datetime
$ rails db:migrate
```

Run rails console to create faker datas for Event model:

```
$ rails console
> Event.new(name: "Event 1", starts_at: Time.now).save
> Event.new(name: "Event 2", starts_at: Time.now).save
> Event.new(name: "Event 3", starts_at: Time.now).save
> Event.new(name: "Event 4", starts_at: Time.now).save
```

Create app/javascript/packs/convert.js with content:

```
jQuery(function(){
  // alert(12345)
  $("span[data-utc-time]").each(function() {
    var timestamp = $(this).attr("data-utc-time");
    var localeTimestamp = new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString();
    $(this).html(localeTimestamp);
});
})
```

Include this javascript in app/views/pages/home.html.erb

```
Welcome to project railstrace !
<% @events.each do |e| %>
  <p> <%= e.name %>: 
  <span data-utc-time="<%= e.starts_at %>">&nbsp;</span>
  </p>
<% end %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'convert' %>
```

Route config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 root to: "pages#home"
end
```

In app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @events = Event.all
  end
end
```

This is just example use simple javascript, with some advance processes for datetime, you can use the lib dayjs.

If have any problems, tell me, I will try to help you, Lemon!

**Update code to use dayjs:**

Edit file app/javascript/packs/convert.js with content:

```
jQuery(function(){
  //Extend dayjs plugin 
  var relativeTime = require('dayjs/plugin/relativeTime')
  dayjs.extend(relativeTime)
  // alert(dayjs().from(dayjs('2021-05-19 11:21:55 UTC'), true) )
  $("span[data-utc-time]").each(function() {
    var timestamp = $(this).attr("data-utc-time")
    var localeTimestamp = new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString()
    var fromNow = dayjs().from(dayjs(timestamp), true)
    var content = `Start at: ${localeTimestamp}. Ago: ${fromNow}`
    // $(this).html(localeTimestamp)
    $(this).html(content)
});
})
```

[image]

Comment: I am having difficulties in order to pass the datetime attribute to js and return the converted result to views, can u help with erb?

Comment: Give me a mini detail exercise such as what things do you have in controller, what things do you want to show, what things do you want javascript codes work. I will try to answer you in updated answer!

Comment: in controller I have only "@events = Event.all" (action index). on index.html.erb I want "@events.each {|e| e.starts_at }" and I want to know how convert this  UTC datetime from database to clients time using dayjs.

Comment: I added dayjs to rails application, but I don’t know how to apply. "  const dayjs = require('dayjs');
  let now = dayjs();
  console.log(now.format());" works from applications.js

Comment: I updated my answer with javascript example show the local date time. Check it!

Comment: Invalid Date :(

Comment: why convert.js doesn't have dayjs calls?

Comment: I updated code use dayjs plugin relativeTime to use function `dayjs().from`. Check it!

Comment: bro help me pls with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67634735/actionviewtemplateerror-webpacker-cant-find-convert-public-packs-manif