# ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find convert .../public/packs/manifest.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

```
   "custom": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/custom-bd99cbe729bdd43682f9.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/custom-bd99cbe729bdd43682f9.js.map"
      ]
    },
    "local-time": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/local-time-2924147712ba915f33c4.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/local-time-2924147712ba915f33c4.js.map"
      ]
    }
  },
  "local-time.js": "/packs/js/local-time-2924147712ba915f33c4.js",
  "local-time.js.map": "/packs/js/local-time-2924147712ba915f33c4.js.map"
}
):
[361192b7-fa0b-4eae-bc92-fa93df67e049]     77:     </div>
[361192b7-fa0b-4eae-bc92-fa93df67e049]     78:   </div></br>
[361192b7-fa0b-4eae-bc92-fa93df67e049]     79: <% end %>
[361192b7-fa0b-4eae-bc92-fa93df67e049]     80: <%= javascript_pack_tag 'convert' %>
```

I added custom js file in my rails app "convert.js" now this throws an error:
how can I fix it? maybe I can remove manifest.json from gitignore?

events.html.erb:

```
<% @events.each do |e| %>
  <%= e.name %>
  <span class="events" data-utc-time="<%= e.starts_at.iso8601 %>"></span>
<% end %> 
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'convert' %>
```

convert.js:

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
require('dayjs/locale/ru')
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat)
const events = document.querySelectorAll('.events');
events.forEach(event => {
  console.log(event.dataset.utcTime)
  const date = dayjs(event.dataset.utcTime).locale(userLang).format('D MMM, HH:mm');
  event.innerText = date;
});
```

Comment: Where do you put "convert.js" ? At `app/javascript/packs/convert.js` ?

Comment: yes app/javascript/packs/convert.js

Comment: Edit your question with erb file (contain convert.js), I doubt in it!

Comment: updated. take a look, please. manifest.json doesn't contain convert.js. I think problem is here

Comment: I tested in my program by rename convert.js to convertxyz.js. It show same error with you, are you sure you put it in the right folder?

Comment: sure.cuz it works on development env, and crashes in production. on my local machine manifest.json contains this file, and I dont see it into manifest on production

Comment: Or Rails version? Check `$ rails -v`! Mine is Rails 6.1.3.2

Comment: $ rails -v                                                                                                     1 ↵  ✹master 
Rails 6.0.3.4

Comment: Check here: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1249

Comment: Test this way: Change config/environments/production.rb:
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
To:
`config.public_file_server.enabled = true`

Comment: I am using nginx. its not a suitable solution for me

Comment: How about this way: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1249#issuecomment-447154510

Comment: it is still not compatible with nginx((

Comment: Check it: https://acuments.com/rails-serve-static-files-with-nginx.html